# Getting the center of a grid's cell - unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm working on an isometric game with Unity and I need to know the centre of the cell in the world coordinates. I'm using the tilemap's `GetCellCenterWorld()` method, but it gives me back bad results.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anAOZ.png) is what I expect to be the centre of the cell (basically the logical centre), but [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajP0P.png) is what Unity gives back (the top vertex of the cell?). I believe it has something to do with the sprite's pivot point (now set to its top centre) or the cell anchor in the tilemap's properties (I set it to **(1,1)**).

Here's the code I use to "select" the tiles:

```cs
public class GridSelection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Tilemap tilemap;
    public Transform selector;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        worldPos.z = 0;

        Vector3Int tilemapPos = tilemap.WorldToCell(worldPos);
        selector.position = tilemap.GetCellCenterWorld(tilemapPos);
    }
}
```

How do I get the actual middle point of the cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I think I found what the issue was.

If anyone has the same problem, here's how I resolved it:

1. Set the sprite pivot point to the place you want the middle of the cell to be (in my case, the centre of the grass section)
2. Set tile anchor back to **(0.5, 0.5)**
3. Use the `GetCellCenterWorld()` method normally

The code I've posted in the question works just fine now.

Answer (score 1):

```
[SerializeField] private Tilemap map;
private Camera camera;
[SerializeField] private Transform playerTransform;

void Start(){
    camera = Camera.main;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update(){
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        var worldPos = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3Int tilemapPos = map.WorldToCell(worldPos);
        playerTransform.position = map.CellToWorld(tilemapPos);
        Debug.Log(tilemapPos);
    }
}
```

> playerTransform.position = map.CellToWorld(clickedCellPosition);

Just convert it back and provide `tilemapPos`

Answer (score 0):

Try tilemap.cellBounds.center
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives me the center of the tilemap instead of the center of an actual tile :/